# Average aggregation on date datatype in Elasticsearch?

Tags: date, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

I have stored the 3 date datatype variable (date1, date2, date3) in my index using a stored script. I have calculated duration between two date variables(date2 - date1) and stored in the third date variable (date3). Here is my complete mapping, scripts and update requests that I have used.

```
PUT /myindex

POST /myindex/_mappings
{
  "properties":{
    "date1":{
      "type":"date"
    },
    "date2":{
      "type":"date"
    },
    "date3":{
      "type":"date"
    }
  }
}

POST _scripts/myindexscript/
{
  "script":{
    "source" :"""

          if (ctx._source.date1==null) {
            ctx._source.date1 = new Date().getTime();
          }
          ctx._source.status.add(params.status);
          if (!(params.status).equalsIgnoreCase('Info')) {
              ctx._source.date2 = new Date().getTime();
              ctx._source.date3=ctx._source.date2 - ctx._source.date1;
          }

    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}

POST /myindex/_update/1
{
  "script":{
    "id":"myindexscript",
    "params":{
      "status": "Infoa"
    }
  }
  , "upsert": {
    "date1":null,
    "date2":null,
    "date3":null,
    "status": []
  },
  "scripted_upsert": true
}
```

I have inserted 1 document as you can see here. For insertion in the document I first run the _update request with field status='Info' and then field status!='Infoa'. Here you can see output of GET /myindex/_search

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date3" : 5589,
          "date2" : 1590062272146,
          "date1" : 1590062266557,
          "status" : [
            "Info",
            "Infoa"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I run this particular aggregation request

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status.keyword": {
        "value": "Infoc"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "date3"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}
```

Which give this weird output :

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.8025915,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.8025915,
        "_source" : {
          "date3" : 5589,
          "date2" : 1590062272146,
          "date1" : 1590062266557,
          "status" : [
            "Info",
            "Infoa"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "value" : 1.142046432E14,
      "value_as_string" : "5589-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

why in aggregation result the value is not 5589 but "value" : 1.142046432E14 . I am not able to understand how date3 field is processed for average calculation. Kindly help ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference of two millisecond-timestamp dates is an integer. In your case

```
1590062272146 - 1590062266557 = 5589
```

Since your mapping stipulates `date3` to be of type `date`, ES attempts to parse it. It guesses it's a year and so the resulting date is `Jan 1st, year 5589`, which in milliseconds is indeed `1.142046432E14`, i.e. `114204643200000`.

So the math is right.

---

Now,

`date2` in UTC is `Thu May 21 2020 11:57:52`

`date1` in UTC is `Thu May 21 2020 11:57:46`

so the difference of the two, rounded up, is 6 seconds.

You now have basically two options:

- call `date3` something else like `milli_diff` and make it an `integer` instead of `date`. Then your `avg` agg result will be in milliseconds too
- make `date3` default to the `format` of `epoch_millis` and perform your date magic on that (such as pretty-printing the avg elapsed difference in a `scripted_metric` aggregation [like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61510171/8160318))

Comment: Hey! thank you for the reply. I have tried both of your suggested options and they are working good enough for me ...... But can you clear my one doubt .... I thought of that it is taking it as a year instead of epoch_millis but why ? In mapping of date datatypes when no format is specified it takes it as a default which is strict_date_optional_time||epoch_milis. So why it is not taking it as epoch_millis.   One more thing when I insert just 1 element named 'Info' into status array of a doc and run the aggregation script with status.keyword value='Info' it gives the correct expected output.

Comment: Now that I've tried it again, I cannot replicate it -.- It is as you say it should be -- `strict_millis`...

Comment: Yes .... That was what I was not able to get ...why this dual behaviour .... :/